# How to show Data labels on the Pie Chart built using ngx-charts library?

Tags: angular, charts, ngx-charts

I am displaying Pie charts on the UI using ngx-charts library. But i am not been able to show data values(labels) inside the chart.How to do with existing attributes provided by ngx-charts or any customisation can be done to do it.

Currently in my HTML file i am rendering Pie chart using following Code:

```
 <ngx-charts-pie-chart 
    [view]="view" 
     [scheme]="colorScheme3"
    [results]="productUtilisations" 
    [legend]="true" 
    [legendPosition]="below"
    (select)="onSelect($event)">
  </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz code?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-charts

Comment: Please find the updated link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-charts-jqflrs

Comment: Which npm library you have used?

Comment: Check this working here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-charts-jqflrs

Comment: Is it fine....?

Comment: Not been able to run.. screen is stuck at Instantiating bundle

Comment: For example....?

Answer (score 1):

has `labels` property defaulted as `false`.

Try with these props:

```
<ngx-charts-pie-chart 
    [view]="view" 
    [scheme]="colorScheme3"
    [results]="productUtilisations" 
    [legend]="true" 
    [legendPosition]="below"
    (select)="onSelect($event)"
    [labels] = "true"
> </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

Ref: https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/pie-charts/pie-chart

Peace.